# Effective way to speed-up my mass-univariate problem (i.e. a large set of per-point optimization problems)

Tags: optimization, large-data

I am new to numerical methods, and I have to solve a problem of medical imaging. My background is computer science. I have a naive, general question.

**Problem Statement:**

I have an extremly large set of points, called '*voxels*' subsequently. The set is denoted by $V$. For each voxel $v\in V$, I have to solve  a standard optimization problem related to the voxel $v$, *i.e.*,

> Find the parameter $p_{min}$ s.t. $d(o^v,p_{min}) \leq  d(o^v,p)$ holds for all possible parameters $p$

Above, $o^v$ is an observation at the  voxel $v$, $d$ is a problem-specific (non-linear in my case) objectiver function   depending on observations and model parameters. 
 Solving this optimization problem voxel by voxel gives a correct result. However, this naive approach is not feasible as the number of voxels in V  quickly becomes large.

**My question is as follows:**

Is there a general approach to deal with such difficulty? I am trying to find some "global method" that gives approximate solution in reasonable time. However, whenever I type "global optimization problem", I will fall into articles talking about solving global minimum  (v.s. local minimum) which is different from what I need.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This may depend on the specific local behaviour of your observed function.

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the actual nature of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an efficient way to find $p_{min}$ in a particular voxel, there are possible hacks to speed-up the mass-univariate problem (I would not call it global as it is indeed confusing).

If you can assume that $p_{min}$ is spatially smooth, you can harness any voxel to solve neighboring voxels. Say you use an iterating method to solve $p_{min}$, just use one solution as initialization for its neighbors.

If you cannot assume spatial smoothness in $p_{min}$, there might be hope to harness power in from parameters. If there are no more parameters, or no smoothness in any of them- the "global" problem is nothing more than a mass of separate problems.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_{min}$ is not smooth you might do a grid search over a representative sample of $o^v$ values where the number of samples selected is less than V (but still high enough to be sufficient) and are either evenly spaced across the scale or in density space.

Comment: Thank you. I see your point. I am looking for an existing tool for this purpose.

Comment: You mean a specific computational solution?  Grid searches are a standard methodological tool.  A quick search showed several instantiations: http://exposurescience.org/heR.doc/library/heR.Misc/html/optgrid.html http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/R.basic/html/gridOptim.html ... but there were many more.